4d Riemannian Manifold as Part of 4d Lorentzian Manifold
If I'm understanding correctly, this paper talks about the union of an initial space-like hypersurface and a final one after a change in spatial topology as the boundary of a 4d manifold. But is a 4d Riemannian manifold needed in this case to construct the 4d Lorentzian manifold? Also, as an aside, I don't know how to find a function that run smoothly and monotonically from $0$ to $1$ as $t$ goes from $1$ to $1$.

a function that run smoothly and monotonically from 0 to 1 as t goes from 1 to 1 Is “from 1 to 1” a typo? It doesn’t make any sense.

I was thinking that too, but that’s what it says in the paper. It does mention that $t$ is periodic, but that doesn’t necessarily make it make more sense.

The 4-Riemannian manifold is a useful starting point, because a Riemannian metric always exists given that it only requires paracompactnes (contrary to the Lorentzian metric that has topological obstructions).
About the second point, as expressed in the comments, it is clearly a typo. The phrase should be
"[the function] $a$ passes smoothly and monotonically from 0 to 1 as $t$ runs from 0 to 1, with vanishing derivative at $t=0$".
As an example you can consider a bump function.

What do you think he meant instead?

"$a$ passes smoothly and monotonically from $0$ to $1$ as $t$ runs
from $0$ to $1$, with vanishing derivative at $t= 0$".
